# How to update DatagridView with SQL request?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

Sorry for my English i'm french.

I would like to update my datagrid with my SQL Server.

How to update when changes Datagrid?

INSERT :

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=***; user id=floflobel; password=***; database=floflobel")

    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM eleves where classe ='" & ListBox1.Text & "'", con)
    Dim aze As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(aze)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = aze
    con.Close()
```

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Search on DataGrid TwoWay Binding and you'll find your way,

Comment: Thank's for your help, not working http://gyazo.com/5002ef580235bcb82c3e2b44686784d4 not detect when tick !